# smood shading turning out odd

Tags: modeling, retopology, smooth

I am currently working on a model of a cat.
I sculpted the model and then finished making retopology.
Now I would like to smood shade it and go make materials, but the smooth shading isn't turning out well. Square's appear on the cat's face so I would like to remove it...

Thing's I've already checked.

1. Face orientation. I made sure everything is blue on overlay.
2. Retopology's angle are smooth and not too sharp.

[image: Before smooth shading]

[image: after smooth shading]

Comment: may be custom normals? Could you check?

Comment: please share your file (or at least a part where you see the problem): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=3PW6YL3e" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3PW6YL3e/)
here.

Comment: merge by distance until it is ok

Comment: it worked! thankyou.